# continuous sending of data

Tags: android, usb, led, accessory

The android application is bulit in such a way that when data is being sent(on clicking the button) to the usb device ,LED toggles and the data is being displayed. I want data to be sent continuously without any manual intervention. Kindly help

```
   if (mInputStream != null)
       {
          int Data = 0;
           try {
             Data = mInputStream.read();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           }
            if (Data == LED_ON)
            {

            ledStatus.setText("LED is ON");             
            }
             else if (Data == LED_OFF)
            {

            ledStatus.setText("LED is OFF");                                
            }
        else
        {
            ledStatus.setText("Request failed");                
        }

            }
           else 
            {
        ledStatus.setText("mInputStream == null");

            }
```

Comment: your question is totally unclear ..refresh it

Comment: What is the specific excepted behaviour?  What is the detailed CURRENT behaviour?

Comment: I want the data usb is receiving should be sent to the screen continuously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this time I have tested it myself...
it should definitely work
paste it in your onCreate() good luck :)

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
              public void run(){
                           // write the method name here. which you want to call continuously
                  Log.d("timer", "timer");
                  }
                  },10, 1000);
```

Comment: when m clicking the button then LED toggles n data exchange takes place. I want data exchange to take place without me touching the button

Comment: this time I have tested it myself... it should definitely work paste it in your onCreate() good luck :)

Comment: could you do me a favour of accepting it as correct answer :) (by clicking on the left check)

Comment: Can you please help me in appending strings once the character is completely transferred??

Comment: add into a function with string as arguement ` public String str(String addString){ addString = "addString" + "addString"; return addString`}